# Does FUSE support O_DIRECT/directI/O

Tags: linux, ubuntu, io, fuse

Hello Linux FUSE (Filesystem in Userspace) support O_DIRECT?
because I use fio benchmark to test fuse but it always shows errors when I use directIO

Mine machine is Ubuntu 4.4.0-38 x86_64
fio_version = 2.14
Below is my config file

```
[global]
ioengine=libaio
**direct=1**
time_based
runtime=60
ramp_time=30
size=64g
group_reporting

[S_100RW_1M_R]
rw=read
numjobs=1
iodepth=32
bs=1m
stonewall

[S_100RW_1M_W]
rw=write
numjobs=1
iodepth=32
bs=1m
stonewall
```

when I execute :`sudo fio fio.cfg` and it done
it shows the result of seq. read without seq. write.
it shows below:

```
fio: io_u error on file xxxxx : Invalid argument: write offset=0, buflen=1048576
```

I tried every times and the results are the same even I changed the tested device.

how come it happened?

thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, [since version 2.4](https://github.com/libfuse/libfuse/blob/44346a9885cb4567ea29c4cb089b1f249c0e46c2/NEWS#L128):

> What is new in 2.4
>
> ...
>
> - Allow 'direct_io' and 'keep_cache' options to be set on a    case-by-case basis on open.

I'd venture one of several things is likely happening:

1. Your version of fuse isn't new enough.
2. The actual underlying file system doesn't support direct IO, and fuse is simply returning a pass-through error. (This does assume fuse passes the direct IO request through to the underlying file system that actually holds the data on disk somewhere.)
3. A bug somewhere in fuse code.  Direct IO on Linux can be very particular/quirky.

Comment: Is possible that speed of Read/Write a large diffrence?